# Can individual lists be grouped together in a folder to save space?

Tags: list, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

Sorry if this is a basic question that has an easy answer to, but I’m new to using Sharepoint and am suck.

I need to create 30 individual lists on my team’s Sharepoint site. I know how to do this, and I know that they’ll all appear on the left hand navigation panel on the home page.

Because there are so many lists, is there a way to place all of these individual lists into a folder? Or can the lists be placed somewhere else on the Sharepoint and not on the left hand side? I’d like to reduce the number of lists on the left hand side of the main page (there are already different lists on there from my team), and would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Placing all of these individual lists into a folder is not available.

You could edit left navigation to reduce the number of lists on the left hand side of the main page.

Go to <kbd>Site Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Look and Feel</kbd> -> <kbd>Navigation</kbd>.

Then you could go to site contents to find lists created.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for your help! I will look into that.

Comment: If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.